# Basis for $p_1(x), p_2(x) \in Q[x]^2$ such that $x^2p_1(x)=(x^2+x)p_2(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I wish to give a basis for $p_1(x), p_2(x) \in Q[x]^2$ such that
$x^2p_1(x)=(x^2+x)p_2(x)$. My thinking is to express $p_1(x)$ as a combination of
$p_2(x)$ or vice versa but I am not sure how to proceed. Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ and $x+1$ are irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$, so $p_1(x)$ must be divisible by $x+1$ and $p_2(x)$ by $x$.  The solutions are $p_1(x) = (x+1) u(x)$, $p_2(x) = x u(x)$, where $u(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$.  What's a basis for that?

Comment: Is it $[x,x+1]^T$ ??

Comment: You probably mean $[x+1,x]^T$: that's one member of the basis, but there are infinitely many.